# Convert class properties into a list of strings

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How do you convert the names of public properties of a class into a list of strings?  Syntax preferably in VB.NET.

I was trying to do something like this:

```
myClassObject.GetType().GetProperties.ToList()
```

However, I need a List(Of String)

Comment: Get the name of each property.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Getting the name of each property? Use LINQ to project each `PropertyInfo` using the LINQ [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891) method, selecting the [`MemberInfo.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name.aspx) property.

```
myClassObject.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList()
```

Or in VB, I think it would be:

```
myClassObject.GetType.GetProperties.Select(Function (p) p.Name).ToList
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is it possible to do this at the class level rather than at the object level?  Can I do Class.GetProperties() or something similar?

Comment: @Prabhu yes, change `myClassObject.GetType()` to `GetType(ClassName)`

Comment: @Prabhu: Or `typeof(Foo).GetProperties()` in C#.

Answer (score 2):

```
var propertyNames = myClassObject.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

Or if you know the type you want to use in advance, you can do:

```
var propertyNames = typeof(ClassName).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```